# OpenCv Python Operation on image,is there a way to do that?

Tags: python, opencv

Is there something in opencv to accomplish the following code?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('test.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
rows,cols,depth = img.shape

for j in range(1,cols-1):
    for i in range(rows):
        if gray[i,j] != 255 and gray[i,j-1] == 255 and gray[i,j+1] == 255:#this is the condition I want to perform on entire image pixel by pixel
            img[i,j]=(255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I did a look at filter2d without lucky. My idea was to perform with different kernels to accomplish the condition in the code above.
I'm not a master of opencv so every advice is welcome
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to elaborate more on the question, i think you need to enhance the white area of the image , if so you just can use a mask or some filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV by creating masks for each of the 3 conditions and then combining the masks before apply to the image.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold at 254 to capture only white pixels
- For the center pixel, invert the threshold image as maskC
- For the right pixel, roll the threshold image to the left by one pixel as maskR
- For the left pixel, roll the threshold image to the right by one pixel as maskL
- Do two bit-wise ANDs to combine the 3 masks into one
- Apply the resulting mask to the image
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
img = cv2.imread('barn.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold at 255 to capture only values at 255
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# create center pixel mask: white if not 255
maskC = 255 - thresh

# create right pixel mask: white if equals 255
# roll the threshold image left by 1 to align the right pixel with the center pixel
maskL = np.roll(thresh, -1, axis=1)

# create left pixel mask: white if equals 255
# roll the threshold image right by 1 to align the right pixel with the center pixel
maskR = np.roll(thresh, 1, axis=1)

# combine masks
mask = cv2.bitwise_and(maskC, maskL)
mask = cv2.bitwise_and(mask, maskR)

# apply mask to image
result = img.copy()
result[mask==255] = (255,255,255)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('barn_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('barn_processed.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

There are too few pixels to see in the processed image, so I will just show the mask.

[image]

To demonstrate that this is correct, here is the original code modified to show the pattern of points.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('barn.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

rows,cols,depth = img.shape

pattern = np.zeros_like(img)

for j in range(1,cols-1):
    for i in range(rows):
        if gray[i,j] != 255 and gray[i,j-1] == 255 and gray[i,j+1] == 255:#this is the condition I want to perform on entire image pixel by pixel
            pattern[i,j]=(255,255,255)
            img[i,j]=(255,255,255)

cv2.imwrite('barn_pattern_true.png', pattern)
cv2.imwrite('barn_processed_true.png', img)

cv2.imshow('pattern',pattern)
cv2.imshow('result',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Pattern image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it is exactly what I was looking for, it is a great example for all the future operations I will perform on the image

Comment: The concept is correct. But the threshold is done wrong. I will fix that a bit later today. The example is incorrect until I present the correct one. The threshold needs to be absolute at 254 and not using otsu.

Comment: I have now corrected my code to fix the threshold error. I show that the same pattern of points is found by my code and the original code. If the OP has a better image, please provide a link and I will replace the image and results.